# Issue creating cyclic model cluster in EXTJS with Jackson

Tags: extjs, jackson

I'm meeting an issue with EXT-JS and Jackson when creating a new model cluster.

Which generates the following issue :

> ERROR fr.package.extjs.web.controller.AbstractSpringController  - ERROR on 
>   inscriptionDetail.validerInscription
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Could not resolve Object Id [-42] (for [simple type, class 
>   fr.package.inoe.inscription.vo.InscriptionJourneeTypeVO]) -- unresolved forward-reference? 
>   (through reference chain: 
>   fr.package.inoe.inscription.vo.InscriptionDetailVO["listeSemainesType"]->fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionSemaineTypeVO["listeJourneesType"]->fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionJourneeTypeVO["listeCreneauxType"]->fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionCreneauTypeVO["journeeType"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve Object Id [-42] (for [simple type, class fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionJourneeTypeVO]) -- unresolved forward-reference? (through reference chain: fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionDetailVO["listeSemainesType"]->fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionSemaineTypeVO["listeJourneesType"]->fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionJourneeTypeVO["listeCreneauxType"]->fr.package.app.inscription.vo.InscriptionCreneauTypeVO["journeeType"])
>       at fr.package.extjs.utils.JSONUtils.fromJsonString(JSONUtils.java:44)

---

Here are how my models are anotated in java:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class InscriptionSemaineTypeVO extends InoeVO<SemaineType, Long> implements java.lang.Comparable<InscriptionSemaineTypeVO> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Long id;
private int version;
private int tri;

//   @JsonBackReference("Inscription-listeSemainesType")
private InscriptionDetailVO inscription;

//  @JsonManagedReference("InscriptionSemaineTypeVO-listeJourneesType")
private List<InscriptionJourneeTypeVO> listeJourneesType;

private long arrondiInMilli;
```

### [...]

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class InscriptionJourneeTypeVO extends InoeVO<JourneeType, Long> implements java.lang.Comparable<InscriptionJourneeTypeVO> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// -------------------------------------------------------------- Attributs.

public Long id;
private int version;
private int numero;
private boolean repas;
private Time arrondi;

//  @JsonBackReference("InscriptionSemaineTypeVO-listeJourneesType")
private InscriptionSemaineTypeVO semaineType;

//  @JsonManagedReference("InscriptionJourneeTypeVO-listeCreneauxType")
private List<InscriptionCreneauTypeVO> listeCreneauxType;
```

### [...]

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class InscriptionCreneauTypeVO extends InoeVO<CreneauType, Long> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Long id;
private int version;
private Time arrivee;
private Time depart;
private Time arrondi;

//  @JsonBackReference("InscriptionJourneeTypeVO-listeCreneauxType")
private InscriptionJourneeTypeVO journeeType;
```

### [...]

Here are my EXTJS models :

---

```
Ext.define('AM.model.inscription.InscriptionSemaineTypeVO', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
            {name: 'id',      type: 'int'},
            {name: 'version',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'tri',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'inscription',      type: 'int'},
            {name: 'listeJourneesType'},
            {name: 'arrondiInMilli',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'persistantClass',      type: 'string'}
        ],
        associations: 
        [
            {
                type : 'hasMany',
                name: 'listeJourneesType',
                model: 'AM.model.inscription.JourneeType'
            },
        ]
```

});

---

```
Ext.define('AM.model.inscription.JourneeType', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
            {name: 'numero',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'repas',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'arrondi',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'semaineType'},
            {name: 'listeCreneauxType'},
            {name: 'id',      type: 'int'},
            {name: 'version',      type: 'int'}
    ],
    associations: 
    [
        {
            type : 'hasMany',
            name: 'listeCreneauxType',
            model: 'AM.model.inscription.CreneauType'
        },
        {
            type : 'hasOne',
            name: 'semaineType',
            model: 'AM.model.inscription.InscriptionSemaineTypeVO'
        },
    ]
    });
```

---

```
Ext.define('AM.model.inscription.CreneauType', 
{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: 
        [
            {name: 'arrivee',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'depart',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'arrondi',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'journeeType'},
            {name: 'uid',      type: 'string'},
            {name: 'id',      type: 'int'},
            {name: 'version',      type: 'int'}
        ],
        associations: 
        [
            {
                type : 'hasOne',
                name: 'journeeType',
                model: 'AM.model.inscription.JourneeType'
            },
        ],
```

});

---

And finally, this is what I am doing in order to create those models:

```
var newSemaine = Ext.create("AM.model.inscription.InscriptionSemaineTypeVO", {
                                                inscription : inscriptionId,
                                                id : -1,
                                            //'arrondiInMilli' : '',
                                            //'attributsVO' : '',
                                            //listeJourneesType : newJournee.data,
                                            //'tri' : '',
                                            //'id' : '',
                                            });

var newJournee = Ext.create("AM.model.inscription.JourneeType", {
                id :-2,
                arrondi : "00:00:00",
            });



var newCreneau = Ext.create("AM.model.inscription.CreneauType" ,{
            arrivee : "00:00:00",
            depart: "00:00:00",
            arrondi : "00:00:00",
            id : -3,
        });

            newJournee.set(
            {
                semaineType : newSemaine.data.id,
                listeCreneauxType : newCreneau.data,
            });

            newCreneau.set(
            {
//                  journeeType : newJournee.data.id,
                journeeType : -42,
            });

            newSemaine.set({
                listeJourneesType : newJournee.data,
            })


storeParents.getRange()[0].listeSemainesTypeStore.add(newSemaine);
storeParents.getRange()[0].setDirty(true);
```

I've found an issue on the Jackson's github, but there seems to be no fix yet...

Any idea of how I could persist this ?

Thank you by advance! (and sorry for the long post !